# Google Cloud Storage InvalidPolicyDocument caused by the submit field

Tags: google-cloud-storage, plupload

For the past couple of years, I've been using Google Cloud Storage to handle storing files for a project that runs for a couple months every year.  In the process of testing this year, I've been running into issues failing to upload certain files.

This is the response I've been getting:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
  <Message>The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document.</Message>
  <Details>Missing upload</Details>
</Error>
```

As additional background, I use plupload, and its flash runtime, to handle the upload functionality and send the form submit to GCS.

The headers for the request do include an upload field

```
------------KM7gL6Ij5KM7KM7cH2Ij5cH2GI3cH2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
```

and the upload field is specified in the Policy Document I send to GCS

```
{
  "expiration": "2014-09-25T11:32:54.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    ...
    ["eq", "$Upload", "Submit Query"]
  ]
}
```

The only time I get this error is when I try to upload files greater than 100KB in size (file types tested: jpg, png, mp3).

In short, in cases where the file size is greater than 100KB, I get an error telling me that there is no form field for the "upload" variable referenced in the Policy Document, but if the file size is less than 100KB, it accepts the transaction.

I have tried not supplying the "upload" variable as part of the policy document and get the opposite result.

Has anyone encountered something similar or can anyone shed some light on the issue?  I'm unsure at this point if plupload is causing the problem or if GCS in fact ignores the "Upload" (submit) field in certain cases but not in others.

Comment: Are there any conditions on content-type or size in the policy document?  You may be able to narrow down whether this is a plupload issue by making the same request via curl and seeing if you get the same result.

Comment: There is a condition for contenty-type `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]` but not for size.  Was able to get make the request via curl and it worked which means that plupload is causing the problem.